# how to abort QJSEngine evaluation

Tags: c++, qt, qml

If evaluate some script that has infinite loop, how to abort the evaluation process.

for example: evaluate some buggy JS in back thread:

QJSEngine engine;

```
void threadproc() {
    engine.evaluate("while(1){}");
}
```

How to give user a choice to abort the evaluate in main(GUI) thread.

Comment: You can use `QThread::terminate` but the thread won't be able to free memory, mutexes, etc. Maybe you should run JS in a separate process and just terminate the process when necessary.

Comment: This deficiency of QJSEngine is tracked in [QTBUG-49080](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49080). A mitigation would be to use QtScript (which is deprecated, however).

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in Qt 5.14 are new QJSEngine methods to help abort infinite running executions:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#isInterrupted
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#setInterrupted